# POST data into a modelform in the formwizard (django)

Tags: django, django-forms

I have one Booking model. The model is broken up into 4 model forms. I need to POST some data to the first form, so it would be initialized. Is that possible? If so, how?

Here are the relevant forms in forms.py:

```
class ServiceChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ('service', 'object_id', )

class ShuttleBookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ('vehicle', 'date', 'time', 'arriving_by', 'flight_number', 'notes', )

class PersonalInfoBookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'email', )

class GeneralBookingInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ('adults', 'children', 'gadgets', 'accommodation', )
```

Comment: Can we please see your code? Ie. how is the model is broken up into 4 model forms?

Comment: Here's the forms.py code: http://dpaste.org/mawQ2/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you need to populate some [initial values?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) If not, can you describe what needs to be there when you start?